Friction on a rotating lamina (rigid body)
Suppose we place a thin lamina of arbitrary shape and uniform density on a horizontal, uniformly rough (coefficient of friction $\mu$) circular disc that can rotate about a fixed vertical axis passing through its centre. No part of the lamina sticks out from the surface of the disc.
When does the lamina start slipping (i.e. start moving relative to the disc) when we gradually increase the angular velocity $\omega$ of the disc? We increase $\omega$ gradually so we can ignore Eulerian acceleration, i.e. $r \frac{d \omega}{dt}$.
I have a strong suspicion that the following will happen (looking from the disc's rotating frame, with its centre as the origin):

Initially only friction will be enough to balance the centrifugal force on each element of the lamina and there will a net zero internal force on each element. The friction on any element will point radially inward.

As ω increases, friction on some parts (those farthest from the axis) will reach the limit. But internal forces from the other parts will come to the rescue.

Assuming that friction and internal forces can keep each part in equilibrium in the interim, eventually (at maximal ω) all the friction vectors on the lamina will point anti-parallel to the position vector of the CM of the lamina. We know that the net force on the body is the sum of the vector sum of all the friction forces and the net centrifugal force on the body: $$\vec F_{net} = \int d \vec f + m \omega ^2 \vec r_{CM} = 0$$ ($m$ being the mass of the lamina)
So, the sum of all the friction vectors always points radially, but the individual vectors have the freedom to point in different directions until the scenario of maximal ω when they all point in the same direction, i.e. radially, so that they give maximum resultant.


If the lamina has a symmetry axis and we align this axis along a diameter of the disc, this looks almost self evident.
But how do we prove it?
I think in the "interim" (while ω is less than maximal), there are infinitely many solutions for the frictions and internal forces, but the final position looks like I described. Only for uniform density and uniform roughness, decidedly.

Your question is confusing. The fact you suggest the angular velocity can be increased until there is a point where the lamina starts slipping suggest you think the can be a finite positive angular velocity where there is no slippage. This is is not correct. If the there is positive non zero angular velocity relative to the disc and the lamina is rigid, then all parts of the lamina will be slipping. I think what you have in mind, is increasing the torque until the static friction is overcome and the lamina starts rotating relative to the disc.

You also suggest the friction balances the centrifugal force. I would have thought that it was radial tension in the laminar that counteracts the centrifugal force. The friction only acts against the torque trying to rotate the laminar. Are you suggesting a lamina that is very weak (something like an omelet) that it requires friction to stop it expanding and flying apart with increasing centrifugal force?

The first two points are correct, but the 3rd is not entirely right.
Static friction is a reaction force, like the force that keeps you from falling through the floor. It is just strong enough to keep you from moving. It balances the total force on you, provided that force is not strong enough to break the floor. If you hold a weight, the force goes up. If you hold a helium balloon, it goes down.
The force of friction on each part of the lamina is just strong enough to keep that part from moving.
It is easiest to work in a frame where the disk is stationary. Then there is a centrifugal force outward at each point of the lamina. Each point may have internal forces too. Static friction just balances them both.
Imagine a lamina consisting of two small disks connected by a massless string. The string is stretched to a straight line at $45^o$ to the radial line to the center of the disk. Internal force on the outer disk is along the string. Centrifugal force is radially outward.
If you draw a picture you will see that the sum is not parallel to the radius through the center of mass.

I think my 3rd assertion is right too. It works for your example. Can you please show me the picture you are talking about?
